# Moving from normal threads to ExecutorService thread pools in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I had my original threading code which worked well, but since my tasks were shortlived, I decided to use thread pools through `ExecutorService`.

This was my original code

```
public class MyRun implements Runnable
{
    private Socket socket = null;
    public MyRun(Socket s)
    {
        socket = s;
        thread = new Thread(this, "SocketThread");
        thread.start();
    }
    public void run()
    {
        // My actual thread code
    }
}
```

My main program

```
...
ss = new ServerSocket(port);
....
MyRun st = null;
while (!stop)
{
    st = new MyRun(ss.accept());
    st = null;
}
```

New code

```
public MyRun(Socket s)
{
    socket = s;
    thread = new Thread(this, "SocketThread");
}
```

`run()` left unchanged

Changed Main program

```
private static ExecutorService execService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
....
....
while (!stop)
{
    execService.execute(new MyRun(ss.accept()));
}
```

Changed code seems to be working fine, but I just want to make sure there is nothing I am missing. I want all threads to execute simultaneously.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few simple remarks :

- `thread = new Thread(this, "SocketThread");` is no longer needed in MyRun, since the ExecutorService is the one creating and managing the `Thread`s.
- you will want to call `execService.shutDown()` to properly clean up the resources of the executorService.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you're still using blocking I/O. So each connection still consumes the whole thread, and there is little difference whether this thread was created manually or taken from a pool.

To employ thread pool efficiently, you have to use non-blocking I/O (NIO), but it is harder to use.

So the question is, have you enough memory to spend a thread per connection? If yes, continue to use your old code, executor service wouldn't help you. If no, take a NIO library (Netty is most widely known, df4j - almost unknown), and follow its suggestion how to use executor service.

Comment: Couple of things - Is NIO really faster - http://mailinator.blogspot.in/2008/02/kill-myth-please-nio-is-not-faster-than.html. Also, won't using a thread pool be advantageous in terms of the cost of creating a new thread - i.e. each thread runs for a very short time in my case. So may be cost of creating the thread is high as compared to the length of time the thread runs.

Comment: The OP was concerned about creating a new thread for each request--not about using too many concurrent threads. A thread pool alleviates this problem. NIO would be helpful if the volume of requests is consuming too many resources.